# Strange ERROR whit INSERT query PHP e mySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

Hello everyone is 5 hours that I can not find a solution to this stupid mistake, what you see is the result of a var_dump ($ _ POST) ...
I can not figure out what kind of error it is since the database is ok the query is ok ...

I place the whole code and a screenshot of the error

```html
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "progettocantiere";
$password = "";
$dbname = "my_progettocantiere";
try 
{


$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql ="INSERT INTO Cantiere( idCantiere,
nomeCantiere,
codiceCommessa,
indirizzoCantiere, 
comuneCantiere, 
oggettoDeiLavori, 
Committente, 
indirizzoCommittente, 
responsabileDeiLavori, 
indirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori,
telefonoResponsabileDeiLavori,
mailResponsabileDeiLavori,
direttoreDeiLavori,
indirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori,
telefonoDirettoreDeiLavori,
mailDirettoreDeiLavori, 
assistente1,
indirizzoAssistente1,
telefonoAssistente1, 
mailAssistente1,
assistente2,
indirizzoAssistente2,
telefonoAssistente2, 
mailAssistente2,
assistente3,
indirizzoAssistente3,
telefonoAssistente3, 
mailAssistente3,
assistente4,
indirizzoAssistente4,
telefonoAssistente4, 
mailAssistente4,
assistente5,
indirizzoAssistente5,
telefonoAssistente5, 
mailAssistente5,
assistente6,
indirizzoAssistente6,
telefonoAssistente6, 
mailAssistente6,
assistente7,
indirizzoAssistente7,
telefonoAssistente7, 
mailAssistente7,
assistente8,
indirizzoAssistente8,
telefonoAssistente8, 
mailAssistente8,
assistente9,
indirizzoAssistente9,
telefonoAssistente9, 
mailAssistente9,
assistente10,
indirizzoAssistente10,
telefonoAssistente10, 
mailAssistente10,
coordinatoreProgettazzione,
indirizzoCoordinatoreProgettazzione, 
telefonoCoordinatoreProgettazzione,
mailCoordinatoreProgettazzione,
coordinatoreEsecuzione,
indirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione, 
telefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione, 
mailCoordinatoreEsecuzione, 
assistenteCSE1,
telefonoAssistenteCSE1, 
mailAssistenteCSE1, 
assistenteCSE2,
telefonoAssistenteCSE2, 
mailAssistenteCSE2, 
assistenteCSE3,
telefonoAssistenteCSE3, 
mailAssistenteCSE3, 
assistenteCSE4,
telefonoAssistenteCSE4, 
mailAssistenteCSE4, 
assistenteCSE5,
telefonoAssistenteCSE5, 
mailAssistenteCSE5,
assistenteCSE6,
telefonoAssistenteCSE6, 
mailAssistenteCSE6,
assistenteCSE7,
telefonoAssistenteCSE7, 
mailAssistenteCSE7,
assistenteCSE8,
telefonoAssistenteCSE8, 
mailAssistenteCSE8,
assistenteCSE9,
telefonoAssistenteCSE9, 
mailAssistenteCSE9,
assistenteCSE10,
telefonoAssistenteCSE10, 
mailAssistenteCSE10,
affidatariaDeiLavori, 
indirizzoAffidatarioLavori,
telefonoAffidatarioLavori,
mailAffidatarioLavori,
faxAffidatarioLavori,
pIvaAffidatarioLavori,
datoreLavoro, 
indirizzoDatoreDiLavoro,
telefonoDatoreDiLavoro,
mailDatoreDiLavoro,
rspp, 
indirizzzoRspp, 
telefonoRspp,
mailRspp,
medicoCompetente,
indirizzoMedicoCompetente,
telefonoMedicoCompetente,
mailMedicoCompetente,
direttoreDiCantiere, 
indirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere,
telefonoDirettoreDiCantiere,
mailDirettoreDiCantiere,
capoCantiere, 
indirizzoCapoCantiere,
telefonoCapoCantiere,
mailCapoCantiere,
preposto,
indirizzoPreposto,
telefonoPreposto,
mailPreposto,
preposto2,
indirizzoPreposto2,
telefonoPreposto2,
mailPreposto2,
preposto3,
indirizzoPreposto3,
telefonoPreposto3,
mailPreposto3,
preposto4,
indirizzoPreposto4,
telefonoPreposto4,
mailPreposto4,
preposto5,
indirizzoPreposto5,
telefonoPreposto5,
mailPreposto5,
preposto6,
indirizzoPreposto6,
telefonoPreposto6,
mailPreposto6,
preposto7,
indirizzoPreposto7,
telefonoPreposto7,
mailPreposto7,
preposto8,
indirizzoPreposto8,
telefonoPreposto8,
mailPreposto8,
preposto9,
indirizzoPreposto9,
telefonoPreposto9,
mailPreposto9,
preposto10,
indirizzoPreposto10,
telefonoPreposto10,
mailPreposto10,
addettoAntincendio1,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio1, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio1,
mailAddettoAntincendio1,
addettoAntincendio2,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio2, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio2,
mailAddettoAntincendio2,
addettoAntincendio3,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio3, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio3,
mailAddettoAntincendio3,
addettoAntincendio4,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio4, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio4,
mailAddettoAntincendio4,
addettoAntincendio5,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio5, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio5,
mailAddettoAntincendio5,
addettoAntincendio6,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio6, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio6,
mailAddettoAntincendio6,
addettoAntincendio7,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio7, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio7,
mailAddettoAntincendio7,
addettoAntincendio8,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio8, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio8,
mailAddettoAntincendio8,
addettoAntincendio9,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio9, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio9,
mailAddettoAntincendio9,
addettoAntincendio10,
indirizzoAddettoAntincendio10, 
telefonoAddettoAntincendio10,
mailAddettoAntincendio10,
addettoPrimoSoccorso1,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1,
addettoPrimoSoccorso2,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso2,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso2,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso2,
addettoPrimoSoccorso3,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso3,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso3,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso3,
addettoPrimoSoccorso4,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso4,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso4,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso4,
addettoPrimoSoccorso5,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso5,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso5,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso5,
addettoPrimoSoccorso6,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso6,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso6,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso6,
addettoPrimoSoccorso7,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso7,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso7,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso7,
addettoPrimoSoccorso8,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso8,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso8,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso8,
addettoPrimoSoccorso9,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso9,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso9,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso9,
addettoPrimoSoccorso10,
indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso10,
telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso10,
mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso10,
aspp, 
indirizzoAspp, 
telefonoAspp, 
mailAspp,
addettoSicurezza1, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza1, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza1,
mailAddettoSicurezza1,
addettoSicurezza2, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza2, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza2,
mailAddettoSicurezza2,
addettoSicurezza3, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza3, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza3,
mailAddettoSicurezza3,
addettoSicurezza4, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza4, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza4,
mailAddettoSicurezza4,
addettoSicurezza5, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza5, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza5,
mailAddettoSicurezza5,
addettoSicurezza6, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza6, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza6,
mailAddettoSicurezza6,
addettoSicurezza7, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza7, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza7,
mailAddettoSicurezza7,
addettoSicurezza8, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza8, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza8,
mailAddettoSicurezza8,
addettoSicurezza9, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza9, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza9,
mailAddettoSicurezza9,
addettoSicurezza10, 
indirizzoAddettoSicurezza10, 
telefonoAddettoSicurezza10,
mailAddettoSicurezza10) 
VALUES(
'$idCantiere',
'$nomeCantiere',
'$codiceCommessa',
'$indirizzoCantiere',
'$comuneCantiere',
'$oggettoDeiLavori',
'$Committente',
'$indirizzoCommittente',
'$responsabileDeiLavori',
'$indirizzoResponsabileDeiLavori',
'$telefonoResponsabileDeiLavori',
'$mailResponsabileDeiLavori',
'$direttoreDeiLavori',
'$indirizzoDirettoreDeiLavori',
'$telefonoDirettoreDeiLavori',
'$mailDirettoreDeiLavori',
'$assistente1',
'$indirizzoAssistente1',
'$telefonoAssistente1',
'$mailAssistente1',
'$assistente2',
'$indirizzoAssistente2',
'$telefonoAssistente2',
'$mailAssistente2',
'$assistente3',
'$indirizzoAssistente3',
'$telefonoAssistente3',
'$mailAssistente3',
'$assistente4',
'$indirizzoAssistente4',
'$telefonoAssistente4',
'$mailAssistente4',
'$assistente5',
'$indirizzoAssistente5',
'$telefonoAssistente5',
'$mailAssistente5',
'$assistente6',
'$indirizzoAssistente6',
'$telefonoAssistente6',
'$mailAssistente6',
'$assistente7',
'$indirizzoAssistente7',
'$telefonoAssistente7',
'$mailAssistente7',
'$assistente8',
'$indirizzoAssistente8',
'$telefonoAssistente8',
'$mailAssistente8',
'$assistente9',
'$indirizzoAssistente9',
'$telefonoAssistente9',
'$mailAssistente9',
'$assistente10',
'$indirizzoAssistente10',
'$telefonoAssistente10',
'$mailAssistente10',
'$coordinatoreProgettazzione',
'$indirizzoCoordinatoreProgettazzione',
'$telefonoCoordinatoreProgettazzione',
'$mailCoordinatoreProgettazzione',
'$coordinatoreEsecuzione',
'$indirizzoCoordinatoreEsecuzione',
'$telefonoCoordinatoreEsecuzione',
'$mailCoordinatoreEsecuzione',
'$assistenteCSE1',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE1',
'$mailAssistenteCSE1',
'$assistenteCSE2',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE2',
'$mailAssistenteCSE2',
'$assistenteCSE3',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE3',
'$mailAssistenteCSE3',
'$assistenteCSE4',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE4',
'$mailAssistenteCSE4',
'$assistenteCSE5',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE5',
'$mailAssistenteCSE5',
'$assistenteCSE6',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE6',
'$mailAssistenteCSE6',
'$assistenteCSE7',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE7',
'$mailAssistenteCSE7',
'$assistenteCSE8',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE8',
'$mailAssistenteCSE8',
'$assistenteCSE9',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE9',
'$mailAssistenteCSE9',
'$assistenteCSE10',
'$telefonoAssistenteCSE10',
'$mailAssistenteCSE10',
'$affidatariaDeiLavori',
'$indirizzoAffidatarioLavori',
'$telefonoAffidatarioLavori',
'$mailAffidatarioLavori',
'$faxAffidatarioLavori',
'$pIvaAffidatarioLavori',
'$datoreLavoro',
'$indirizzoDatoreDiLavoro',
'$telefonoDatoreDiLavoro',
'$mailDatoreDiLavoro',
'$rspp',
'$indirizzoRspp',
'$telefonoRspp',
'$mailRspp',
'$medicoCompetente',
'$indirizzoMedicoCompetente',
'$telefonoMedicoCompetente',
'$mailMedicoCompetente',
'$direttoreDiCantiere',
'$indirizzoDirettoreDiCantiere',
'$telefonoDirettoreDiCantiere',
'$mailDirettoreDiCantiere',
'$capoCantiere',
'$indirizzoCapoCantiere',
'$telefonoCapoCantiere',
'$mailCapoCantiere',
'$preposto',
'$indirizzoPreposto',
'$telefonoPreposto',
'$mailPreposto',
'$preposto2',
'$indirizzoPreposto2',
'$telefonoPreposto2',
'$mailPreposto2',
'$preposto3',
'$indirizzoPreposto3',
'$telefonoPreposto3',
'$mailPreposto3',
'$preposto4',
'$indirizzoPreposto4',
'$telefonoPreposto4',
'$mailPreposto4',
'$preposto5',
'$indirizzoPreposto5',
'$telefonoPreposto5',
'$mailPreposto5',
'$preposto6',
'$indirizzoPreposto6',
'$telefonoPreposto6',
'$mailPreposto6',
'$preposto7',
'$indirizzoPreposto7',
'$telefonoPreposto7',
'$mailPreposto7',
'$preposto8',
'$indirizzoPreposto8',
'$telefonoPreposto8',
'$mailPreposto8',
'$preposto9',
'$indirizzoPreposto9',
'$telefonoPreposto9',
'$mailPreposto9',
'$preposto10',
'$indirizzoPreposto10',
'$telefonoPreposto10',
'$mailPreposto10',
'$addettoAntincendio1',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio1',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio1',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio1',
'$addettoAntincendio2',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio2',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio2',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio2',
'$addettoAntincendio3',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio3',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio3',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio3',
'$addettoAntincendio4',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio4',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio4',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio4',
'$addettoAntincendio5',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio5',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio5',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio5',
'$addettoAntincendio6',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio6',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio6',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio6',
'$addettoAntincendio7',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio7',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio7',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio7',
'$addettoAntincendio8',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio8',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio8',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio8',
'$addettoAntincendio9',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio9',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio9',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio9',
'$addettoAntincendio10',
'$indirizzoAddettoAntincendio10',
'$telefonoAddettoAntincendio10',
'$mailAddettoAntincendio10',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso1',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso1',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso1',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso2',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso2',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso2',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso2',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso3',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso3',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso3',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso3',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso4',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso4',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso4',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso4',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso5',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso5',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso5',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso5',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso6',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso6',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso6',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso6',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso7',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso7',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso7',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso7',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso8',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso8',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso8',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso8',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso9',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso9',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso9',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso9',
'$addettoPrimoSoccorso10',
'$indirizzoAddettoPrimoSoccorso10',
'$telefonoAddettoPrimoSoccorso10',
'$mailAddettoPrimoSoccorso10',
'$aspp',
'$indirizzoAspp',
'$telefonoAspp',
'$mailAspp',
'$addettoSicurezza1',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza1',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza1',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza1',
'$addettoSicurezza2',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza2',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza2',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza2',
'$addettoSicurezza3',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza3',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza3',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza3',
'$addettoSicurezza4',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza4',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza4',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza4',
'$addettoSicurezza5',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza5',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza5',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza5',
'$addettoSicurezza6',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza6',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza6',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza6',
'$addettoSicurezza7',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza7',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza7',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza7',
'$addettoSicurezza8',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza8',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza8',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza8',
'$addettoSicurezza9',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza9',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza9',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza9',
'$addettoSicurezza10',
'$indirizzoAddettoSicurezza10',
'$telefonoAddettoSicurezza10',
'$mailAddettoSicurezza10')";
//);

    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo "New record created successfully";
    }
 catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = null;
```

Error;

[image]

The query is huge .. there are about 270 fields but the problem is not that the fields are NULL ... because I have checked the possibility to keep them null

I know that mysql is obsolete and I have to update it .. but please avoid linking me how to prevent the injection .. after fixing this bug I put it affixed

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca dato che sei italiano ti scrivo nella nostra lingua .. perché dici così ?

Comment: @AndreaPilenga try to use PDO to prevent the same errors in future.

Comment: It is time to think about re-designing your db

Comment: (Sorry, I'll answer in English for the benefit of others): because that's a complete mess of a table. You shouldn't have ten fields to represent ten entities, you sholud have ten rows somewhere else linked with the one you're inserting. This is not the place for a lesson in databases, but I suggest you learn about [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Federico, I am very informed about normalization and multiple attributes ... but in the situation in which I find myself and the project that I have to realize my only option is this
@FedericoklezCulloca

Comment: Anyway, you're missing a closing quote at `$mailAssistente5` in the query. That's the problem

Comment: how to design large application database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393845/large-application-database-design-like-flipkart

Comment: ty @FedericoklezCulloca